# Action Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, action

I have moveToElement in builder action and doesn't work. The error is in the line 19.
   `builder.moveToElement(nav.findElement(By.className("dropbtn"))).build().perform();`

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST
>   /session/91b7605c-441d-444a-b98c-e8001bb79144/moveto did not match a
>   known command (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 3 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:52:30
>   -0700' System info: host: 'Torre-Raul', ip: '192.168.1.10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_101' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false,
>   appBuildId=20160823121617, version=, platform=XP, proxy={},
>   command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false,
>   browserVersion=48.0.2, platformVersion=10.0,
>   XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=Firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true,
>   platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}] Session ID:
>   91b7605c-441d-444a-b98c-e8001bb79144  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:631)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove(RemoteMouse.java:89)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveMouseAction.perform(MoveMouseAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:50)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:19)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        FirefoxDriver nav = new FirefoxDriver();
        nav.manage().window().maximize();
        Actions builder = new Actions(nav);
        nav.navigate().to("http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp");
        builder.moveToElement(nav.findElement(By.className("dropbtn"))).build().perform();
        nav.findElement(By.linkText("Link 1")).click();
    }
```